# Sequelize Node Js Seeder file with Many-to-Many Association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to find out what is the right way to add a many-to-many relation when seeding records with sequelize-cli. Now I understand that the easiest way to do this is to create another seeder file and manually set the values but is there a way to make some changes to my 2_user seeder file so that when a user is seeded with some value given for the role it automatically makes a record in the user_roles table. So basically same as the user.setRoles() one can use but in the seeder files. Any help is much appreciated.

**Models**

user.model.js

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        through: 'user_roles',
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        otherKey: 'role_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      });
      User.hasMany(models.User_Role);

      User.hasMany(models.Address, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      });
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      bio: DataTypes.STRING,
      activity_status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

role.model.js

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        through: 'user_roles',
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        otherKey: 'role_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      });
      User.hasMany(models.User_Role);

      User.hasMany(models.Address, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      });
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      bio: DataTypes.STRING,
      activity_status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

user_role.model

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User_Role extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User_Role.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
      });
      User_Role.belongsTo(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: 'role_id',
      });
    }
  }
  User_Role.init(
    {
      user_role_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User_Role',
    }
  );
  return User_Role;
};
```

**Migrations**

1-create-user

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      user_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      bio: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      activity_status: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  },
};
```

3-create-role

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('roles', {
      role_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      user_type: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('roles');
  },
};
```

6-create-user_role

```
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('user_roles', {
      user_role_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'user_id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      role_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'roles', key: 'role_id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('user_roles');
  },
};
```

**Seeders**

1_role

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
      'roles',
      [
        {
          user_type: 'courier',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
        {
          user_type: 'receiver',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
        {
          user_type: 'donor',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
        {
          user_type: 'admin',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
      ],
      {}
    );
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Roles', null, {});
  },
};
```

2_user

```
('use strict');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
      'users',
      [
        {
          email: 'courier@email.com',
          password: bcrypt.hashSync('PassWord123@', 10),
          bio: 'This is a courier type user!',
          activity_status: true,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
          role_id: 1,
        },
        {
          email: 'donor@email.com',
          password: bcrypt.hashSync('PassWord123@', 10),
          bio: 'This is a donor type user!',
          activity_status: true,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
        {
          email: 'receiver@email.com',
          password: bcrypt.hashSync('PassWord123@', 10),
          bio: 'This is a Receiver type user!',
          activity_status: true,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
        {
          email: 'admin@email.com',
          password: bcrypt.hashSync('PassWord123@', 10),
          bio: 'This is a Admin type user!',
          activity_status: true,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
      ],
      {}
    );
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
  },
};
```